# Are chlorinated solvents generally avoided in reducing reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

Are chlorinated solvents incompatible with reducing reagents? Is reductive dechlorination the reason?

There also seems to be exemptions, in *J. Org. Chem.* **1996**, 61, 3849-3862, 1,2-dichloroethane was used as a solvent for a reductive amination reaction. NaBH(OAc)<sub>3</sub> was used as the reducing agent in this paper.

Comment: Dibal-H is commercially available as a solution in dichloromethane   https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/214973?lang=en&region=GB